# How to make select option disable

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make select option read only. When i enter current address it should appear in permanent address this is working fine and when i checked the check box text boxes are being disabled(read only) but drop down is being editable. How to make select option read only.

```js
$('#addressInfo  input:text').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // disabled the textboxes
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">


    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #b3daff;">

          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"> <span style="font-weight: 700;">Address
         Details</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color: darkred">&nbsp;</span>

            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">

            <!--Input for personal details--->

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">Current
          </label>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br /> <br />
            <!-- Address line 1 -->
            <div class="col-md-12">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Address Line 1<span
           style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addressLine1" required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!--end tag for address line 1 -->
            <br /> <br />
            <!-- Address line 2 -->
            <div class="col-md-12">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Address Line 2</label>
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addressLine2" required placeholder="Address Line 2" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!--end tag for address line 1 -->
            <br /> <br />

            <!--city/town code-->
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-5">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-4">City/Town<span
           style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>

                  <div class="col-md-12">

                    <select id="city" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('City Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" />
                    <option hidden value="">City/Town</option>
                    <option value="bng">Bangalore</option>
                    <option value="mng">Mangalore</option>
                    <option value="bl">Ballari</option>

                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!----State-->
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-4">State<span
           style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>

                  <div class="col-md-12">

                    <select id="state" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('City Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" />
                    <option hidden value="">State</option>
                    <option value="kn">Karnataka</option>
                    <option value="an">Andra Pradesh</option>
                    <option value="nd">New Delhi</option>
                    <option value="mb">Mumbai</option>



                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--end of state code-->

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">Pin
           Code<span style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pincode" required placeholder="Pin Code" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <br /><br /><br />
            <!----State-->
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Country<span
           style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>

                  <div class="col-md-12">

                    <select id="country" name="country" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Country Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                      <option hidden value="">Country</option>
                      <option value="in">India</option>



                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>




            <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />


            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-12">Permanent
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Same
           as above &nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="chk">
          </label>


                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!--Input for personal details--->


            <br /> <br /> <br />
            <!-- Address line 1 -->
            <div id="addressInfo">
              <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Address Line 1<span
           style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address1" required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <!--end tag for address line 1 -->
              <br /> <br />
              <!-- Address line 2 -->
              <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Address Line 2</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address2" required placeholder="Address Line 2" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <!--end tag for address line 1 -->
              <br /> <br />

              <!--city/town code-->
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-5">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">City/Town<span
           style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                      <select id="inputCity" name="inputCity" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('City Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" />
                      <option hidden value="">City/Town</option>
                      <option value="bng">Bangalore</option>
                      <option value="mng">Mangalore</option>
                      <option value="bl">Ballari</option>

                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!----State-->
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">State<span
           style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                      <select id="inputState" name="inputState" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('City Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                        <option hidden value="">State</option>
                        <option value="kn">Karnataka</option>
                        <option value="an">Andra Pradesh</option>
                        <option value="nd">New Delhi</option>
                        <option value="mb">Mumbai</option>


                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--end of state code-->

              <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">Pin
           Code<span style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPincode" required placeholder="Pin Code" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br /><br /><br />
              <!----State-->
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Country<span
           style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                      <select id="inputCountry" name="inputCountry" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('City Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                        <option hidden value="">Country</option>
                        <option value="in">India</option>



                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br /> <br /><br />


            </div>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!----Ends second column-------->
```

Comment: please share html code

Comment: What are you trying to select with `input:text`?

Comment: Are you trying to disable an <input> or a <select>

Comment: input being disabled. I am trying to make select and input both should be disabled.

Comment: Try -> `#addressInfo input,select` this will disable both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youu need to add a listener to the checkbox and evaluate if its checked

I added the id `same` to the check box

```
$('#same').change(function(){
    if(this.checked) {
```

You can use the same, `attr` function. Just adapt your selector

```
$('#addressInfo  select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Hope this helps :>

```js
$('#same').change(function(){
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#addressInfo  input:text').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#addressInfo  select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">


    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #b3daff;">

          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"> <span style="font-weight: 700;">Address
         Details</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color: darkred">&nbsp;</span>

            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">

            <!--Input for personal details--->

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">Current
          </label>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br /> <br />
            <!-- Address line 1 -->
            <div class="col-md-12">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Address Line 1<span
           style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addressLine1" required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!--end tag for address line 1 -->
            <br /> <br />
            <!-- Address line 2 -->
            <div class="col-md-12">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Address Line 2</label>
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addressLine2" required placeholder="Address Line 2" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!--end tag for address line 1 -->
            <br /> <br />

            <!--city/town code-->
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-5">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-4">City/Town<span
           style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>

                  <div class="col-md-12">

                    <select id="city" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('City Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" />
                    <option hidden value="">City/Town</option>
                    <option value="bng">Bangalore</option>
                    <option value="mng">Mangalore</option>
                    <option value="bl">Ballari</option>

                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!----State-->
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-4">State<span
           style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>

                  <div class="col-md-12">

                    <select id="state" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('City Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" />
                    <option hidden value="">State</option>
                    <option value="kn">Karnataka</option>
                    <option value="an">Andra Pradesh</option>
                    <option value="nd">New Delhi</option>
                    <option value="mb">Mumbai</option>



                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--end of state code-->

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">Pin
           Code<span style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pincode" required placeholder="Pin Code" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <br /><br /><br />
            <!----State-->
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Country<span
           style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>

                  <div class="col-md-12">

                    <select id="country" name="country" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Country Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                      <option hidden value="">Country</option>
                      <option value="in">India</option>



                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>




            <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />


            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-12">Permanent
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Same
           as above &nbsp;<input id="same" type="checkbox" id="chk">
          </label>


                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!--Input for personal details--->


            <br /> <br /> <br />
            <!-- Address line 1 -->
            <div id="addressInfo">
              <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Address Line 1<span
           style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address1" required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <!--end tag for address line 1 -->
              <br /> <br />
              <!-- Address line 2 -->
              <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Address Line 2</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address2" required placeholder="Address Line 2" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <!--end tag for address line 1 -->
              <br /> <br />

              <!--city/town code-->
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-5">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">City/Town<span
           style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                      <select id="inputCity" name="inputCity" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('City Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" />
                      <option hidden value="">City/Town</option>
                      <option value="bng">Bangalore</option>
                      <option value="mng">Mangalore</option>
                      <option value="bl">Ballari</option>

                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!----State-->
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">State<span
           style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                      <select id="inputState" name="inputState" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('City Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                        <option hidden value="">State</option>
                        <option value="kn">Karnataka</option>
                        <option value="an">Andra Pradesh</option>
                        <option value="nd">New Delhi</option>
                        <option value="mb">Mumbai</option>


                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--end of state code-->

              <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">Pin
           Code<span style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPincode" required placeholder="Pin Code" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br /><br /><br />
              <!----State-->
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Country<span
           style="color: red;">*</span>
          </label>

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                      <select id="inputCountry" name="inputCountry" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('City Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                        <option hidden value="">Country</option>
                        <option value="in">India</option>



                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br /> <br /><br />


            </div>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!----Ends second column-------->
```

Comment: When i uncheck the check box, even select in mode of read only.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand. What result do you expect?

Comment: When I check the check box. Text and select must be disabled. When I uncheck they must be editable.

Comment: just execute below jquery statements when checkbox is unchecked.  $('#addressInfo  input:text').removeAttr('disabled');
$('#addressInfo  select').removeAttr('disabled');

Comment: @Gerardo BLANCO thanks..This is worked for my code. $('#addressInfo  select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$('#addressInfo').find('input:text').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

or :

```
$('#addressInfo').find('input:text').eq(0).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
//for first found input
```

for disable select:

```
$('#inputCountry').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

for disable first option:

```
$('#inputCountry').find('option').eq(0).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Input text is being disabled its working. I need to make disable <select> too.

Answer (score 0):

Try below jquery statement for disabling select field options:

```
$('#addressInfo select').find('option').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Dropdown will work, but as your question suggest that dropdown options should be disabled which makes sure that existing selected option will remain selected only. The given statement will be doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you:

```js
$( '#chk' ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
    if ( this.checked ) {
        $( '#permanent input[type="text"]' ).each( function ( index ) {
            $( this ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' ).val( $( '#current input[type="text"]' ).eq( index ).val() );
        } )
        $( '#permanent select' ).each( function ( index ) {
            $( this ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' ).val( $( '#current select' ).eq( index ).val() );
        } )
    } else {
        $( '#permanent input[type="text"], #permanent select' ).each( function ( index ) {
            $( this ).removeAttr( 'disabled' ).val( '' );
        } )
    }
} )
```

```css
.required {
    color: red
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(140px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
p {
    background-color: #ddd
}
.form-group {
    padding-bottom: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li id="current">
        <p>Current</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="addressLine1">Address Line 1 <em class="required">*</em></label>
            <input type="text" id="addressLine1" placeholder="Address Line 1" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="addressLine2">Address Line 2</label>
            <input type="text" id="addressLine2" placeholder="Address Line 2" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="city">City/Town <em class="required">*</em> </label>
            <select id="city" required />
                <option hidden value="">City/Town</option>
                <option value="bng">Bangalore</option>
                <option value="mng">Mangalore</option>
                <option value="bl">Ballari</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="state">State <em class="required">*</em></label>
            <select id="state" required />
                <option hidden value="">State</option>
                <option value="kn">Karnataka</option>
                <option value="an">Andra Pradesh</option>
                <option value="nd">New Delhi</option>
                <option value="mb">Mumbai</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pincode">Pin Code <em class="required">*</em></label>
            <input type="text" id="pincode" placeholder="Pin Code" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="country">Country <em class="required">*</em></label>
            <select id="country" name="country" required>
                <option hidden value="">Country</option>
                <option value="in">India</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="permanent">
        <p>
            Permanent (
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
            <label for="chk" class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-12">Same as Current</label>
            )
        </p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address1">Address Line 1 <em class="required">*</em></label>
            <input type="text" id="address1" placeholder="Address Line 1" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address2">Address Line 2</label>
            <input type="text" id="address2" placeholder="Address Line 2" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCity">City/Town <em class="required">*</em></label>
            <select id="inputCity" name="inputCity" required />
                <option hidden value="">City/Town</option>
                <option value="bng">Bangalore</option>
                <option value="mng">Mangalore</option>
                <option value="bl">Ballari</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputState">State <em class="required">*</em></label>
            <select id="inputState" name="inputState" required >
                <option hidden value="">State</option>
                <option value="kn">Karnataka</option>
                <option value="an">Andra Pradesh</option>
                <option value="nd">New Delhi</option>
                <option value="mb">Mumbai</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPincode">Pin Code <em class="required">*</em></label>
            <input type="text" id="inputPincode" placeholder="Pin Code" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCountry">Country <em class="required">*</em></label>
            <select id="inputCountry" name="inputCountry" required>
                <option hidden value="">Country</option>
                <option value="in">India</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```